# Apache ignore *.php files in rewrite directives but not other extensions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, php

I'm trying to test some simple rewrite directives in .htaccess file on my test environment with Apache and PHP-FPM.

It seems that a simple rewrite rule works well for any type of file but not for *.php files.

This works :

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule ^sandbox/video\.html?$ http://www.google.fr? [R,L]
```

But this not :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^sandbox/video\.php?$ http://www.google.fr? [R,L]
```

I run Apache 2.2 and PHP-FPM inside a VM on Debian

Could it be related ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why do you use a `?` after `.php` and after `.fr` ? (Its ok after `.html` because that test for `.htm`)

Comment: For me it was to prevent any other characters to be added. But maybe i'm wrong ?

Comment: No, for regex, that indicate a facultative element just before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With PHP-FPM the .htaccess file is never read for php URL. You will need to add the rewrites to your main config.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i was pretty confident that it was related to php-fpm but can't find any source on the subject. Thanks also for the regex clarification.